# SQLITE sum sales by customer and by year

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a sqlite database with this info

| id | pcs | dollars | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 25 | 150 | 2021 |
| 10 | 20 | 160 | 2021 |
| 10 | 22 | 120 | 2022 |
| 11 | 12 | 130 | 2021 |
| 11 | 10 | 100 | 2022 |

I want to get this

| id | pcs2021 | dollars2021 | pcs2022 | dollars2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 45 | 310 | 22 | 120 |
| 11 | 12 | 130 | 10 | 100 |

I got this:

`SELECT id, SUM(pcs), SUM(dollars) FROM Table GROUP BY id`

But I can't find the way to get the SUM of each year separately.

I tried something like:

`SELECT id, (SELECT SUM(pcs) FROM Table WHERE id=id AND year=2021) AS pcs2021, (SELECT SUM(dollars) FROM Table WHERE id=id AND year=2021) AS dollars2021, (SELECT SUM(pcs) FROM Table WHERE id=id AND year=2022) AS pcs2022, (SELECT SUM(dollars) FROM Table WHERE id=id AND year=2022) AS dollars2022, FROM Table GROUP BY id`

but it doesn't work.....

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Using :-

```
SELECT id, SUM(pcs) AS pcs2021, SUM(dollars) AS dollars2021 FROM `Table` WHERE year = 2021 GROUP BY id;
```

results in :-

[image]

- note the above assumes year is an integer so you may have to enclose the literal in single quotes.

**Additional** (re comment)

> My problem is when I want to put different columns with SUM of values for each year

An issue you are having is that id=id will always be true and thus you will sum all rows, irrespective of the id, for the year and get the result (when the syntax is correct):-

[image]

That is **id** is the **id** of the sub query when you want to compare against the **id** currently being processed by the main query.

To do this you can give the main query an alias using the `AS` clause and then refer to the id of the alias so (where the main query is given the alias of **`a`**):-

```
SELECT 
    id,
    (SELECT sum(pcs) FROM `table` WHERE id=a.id AND year='2021') AS pcs2021,
    (SELECT sum(dollars) FROM `table` WHERE id=a.id AND year='2021') AS dollars2021, 
    (SELECT sum(pcs) FROM `table` WHERE id=a.id AND year='2022') AS pcs2022,
    (SELECT sum(dollars) FROM `table` WHERE id=a.id AND year='2022') AS dollars2022
FROM `table` AS a
GROUP BY id
;
```

The result being :-

[image]

- **Note** the use of Table as a table name will result in a syntax error if it is not enclosed as Table is an SQLite keyword.

Comment: Thank you!!! You saved my day.  About "Table" it was just a simplification, but I noted your advise.  It work perfectly, thank you